# pffft equivalent of fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d function from fftw

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, ifft

I am trying to convert my project from using FFTW to pffft. I only need to call the following two functions:

```
int N = 1024;
fftwf_plan planf = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, (float*)in, (fftwf_complex*)out, flags);
fftwf_plan planb = fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, (fftwf_complex*)in, (float*)out, flags);
```

After reading the documentation, I assume these are the equivalent function calls:

```
PFFFT_Setup *s = pffft_new_setup(N, PFFFT_REAL);
pffft_transform(s, input, output, nullptr, PFFFT_FORWARD);
pffft_transform(s, input, output, nullptr, PFFFT_BACKWARD);
```

But `pffft_transform` takes only floats as input and output. Is there a way to do the same **real to complex** and **complex to real** transform like in `FFTW`?

Comment: The [github repository](https://github.com/marton78/pffft/blob/master/pffft.hpp) indicates that Fft.forward and Fft.inverse do what you want. Note the comment on line [124](https://github.com/marton78/pffft/blob/e0bf595c98ded55cc457a371c1b29c8cab552628/pffft.hpp#L124) about float vs. double data types.

Comment: @Ash thanks for pointing it out! I was looking at the original repo: https://bitbucket.org/jpommier/pffft/src/38946c766c1afecfa4c5945af77913e38b3cec31/pffft.h?at=master
And it looks quite different from this fork. I will try it out!